# How to add logging to classes in a module at a custom level

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to replace an old method of logging information with standard Python logging to a file. The application currently has a log file which is set to capture Info and Debug messages so I would like this at a lower level that isn't captured by the main log.

App structure:

```
- mysite
- legacy
  -- items
     --- item1.py
  -- __init__.py
  -- engine.py
```

Within `item1.py` and `engine.py` are calls to an old `debug()` function which I'd not like to be logged in `legacy.log` but not have them appear in the `mysite.log` file.

Ideally the way this works is to create a wrapper with a debug function which does the logging at the new level and I've read that this requires an extension of `logging.Logger`.

So In `legacy/__init__.py` I've written;

```
import logging

LEGACY_DEBUG_LVL = 5

class LegacyLogger(logging.Logger):
    """
    Extend the Logger to introduce the new legacy logging.
    """
    def legacydebug(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Log messages from legacy provided they are strings.

        @param msg: message to log
        @type msg:
        """
        if isinstance(msg, str):
            self._log(LEGACY_DEBUG_LVL, msg, args)

    logging.Logger.legacydebug = legacydebug


logger = logging.getLogger('legacy')
logger.setLevel(LEGACY_DEBUG_LVL)
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('legacy.log'))
logging.addLevelName(LEGACY_DEBUG_LVL, "legacydebug")
```

And from `engine.py` and `item1.py` I can just do;

```
from . import logger
debug = logger.legacydebug
```

At the moment I'm seeing messages logged to both logs. Is this the correct approach for what I want to achieve? I've got a talent for over-complicating things and missing the simple stuff!

*edit*

Logging in the main application settings is setup as such;

```
# settings.py
logging.captureWarnings(True)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
logger.addHandler(logging.handlers.FileHandler('mysite.log'))

if DEBUG:
    # If we're running in debug mode, write logs to stdout as well:
    logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
else:
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: Can you give details on what you do with the logging module in the mysite part? I guess you have another logger which have a FileHandler to 'mysite.log', haven't you?

Comment: @jorispilot sure, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using multiple loggers, the `logging` module implicitly creates them in a tree structure. The structure are defined by the logger name: a logger named `'animal'` will be the parent of loggers called `'animal.cat'` and `'animal.dog'`.

In your case, the unnamed logger defined in `settings.py` is parent of the logger named `'legacy'`. The unnamed logger will receive the messages sent through the `'legacy'` logger, and write them into `mysite.log`.

Try to give a name for the unnamed logger, such as `'mysite'` to break the tree structure.

Comment: Very helpful thanks. My remaining issue now is the default uses of `logging` now appear to be going to the `'root'` logger which doesn't hit either log file. Is the only way to fix that a refactor of logging to replace usage of `logging.` with `logger.` after doing `logger = logging.getLogger('name')`?

Comment: Well, it depends on what it is done by `logging.`. But if this action apply to either 'mysite' or 'legacy', I recommend you use the `logger.` option instead.